# Python 3. How to find any member of one list in another list?

Tags: python-3.x

I have first list:
`x = ["abc", "cde", .... "sadlfj"]`
and the second list.
`y = ["ABC", "DRF", .... "CXV"]`
I need to check the following condition:
if any member of list "x" is in the list "y", then TRUE.
How to write this condition check without iteration?
Thank you

Comment: make them sets and then get the intersection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try sets, since you ask for the condition, not the actual elements in common:

```
x = [...]
y = [...]

if not set(x).isdisjoint(set(y)):
     # they have something in common
```